# How can I delete result of list query in one step?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

I've tried this to delete `operations` where product ID equals to `myProdID`.
It deleted whole operations branch, not just ones equal to query result.

```
this.af.database.list('operations', {
        query: {
          orderByChild: 'products/productID',
          equalTo: myProdID
        }
      }).remove();
```

What shall I use in order to do it in one line of code and not run for loop to remove each item? .map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little more than one line of code, but you could do this:

```js
deleteOperations(productID: any): Observable<any> {

  return this.af.database.list('operations', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'products/productID',
      equalTo: productID
    }
  })

  // AngularFire2 list/object observables don't complete - they re-emit if
  // the database changes - so use the first operator to ensure it completes
  // and ignores subsequent database changes.

  .first()

  // Use Array.prototype.reduce to create an object containing the keys to
  // be removed and use the FirebaseObjectObservable's update method to
  // remove them.

  .mergeMap((ops) => this.af.database.object('operations').update(
    ops.reduce((acc, op) => { acc[op.$key] = null; return acc; }, {})
  ));
}
```

The above function would return an observable and the delete would be performed upon the caller subscribing to it.

If you would prefer to have the function return a promise, you could do something like this:

```js
deleteOperations(productID: any): Promise<any> {

  return this.af.database.list('operations', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'products/productID',
      equalTo: productID
    }
  })

  // AngularFire2 list/object observables don't complete - they re-emit if
  // the database changes - so use the first operator to ensure it completes
  // and ignores subsequent database changes.

  .first()

  // Convert the observable to a promise when that will resolve when the
  // observable completes.

  .toPromise()

  // Use Array.prototype.reduce to create an object containing the keys to
  // be removed and use the FirebaseObjectObservable's update method to
  // remove them.

  .then((ops) => this.af.database.object('operations').update(
    ops.reduce((acc, op) => { acc[op.$key] = null; return acc; }, {})
  ));
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I've looked more to find out about mergeMap,  [https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#mergemap](RxJS 5 Operators By Example) has an example but I couldn't see what is different from yours.

Comment: The `mergeMap` is used to complete the observable when the promise returned by `update` resolves. In what way does it not work?

Comment: Sorry, it did when I subscribed to it. I'm not very good with RxJS stuff. Is there any way it returns a promise. I was planing in my mind to put it in a service function, so when called it returns a promise and it gets resolved in calling component.

Comment: or I can return the Observable mergeMap returns and subscribe to it in the component I guess.

Comment: wait, you are saying I didn't have to subscribe to it? well it didn't remove those nodes (didn't resolve update promise) from Firebase unless I subscribe.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Nothing will happen without a call to `subscribe`. If you'd prefer a promise, I've added an alternative implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a single update like so:

```
ref.update({
  '/operations/products/foo': null,
  '/operations/products/bar': null
});
```

This will batch remove the foo and bar children from `ref/operations/products` while keeping all other children untouched.

But I imagine you would still have to do some looping to figure out which paths to update.